# Launch a new instance of Chrome with a shortcut

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, shortcuts

I have a web app that launches from a shortcut on the desktop. I would like to have it spawn in a new instance of Chrome -- with its own pinnable task bar icon, etc. -- instead of grouped with the rest of my general web browsing activity.

Is it possible to do this without running it in a different browser altogether?
Maybe by using a shortcut to chrome.exe and starting it in a different folder?

I checked the list of command switches [here](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) but it was not clear if any of those would accomplish what I'm looking for.

Comment: When your post is closed as duplicate, asking it again is not the right choice. You should rather explain why it is not a duplicate.

Comment: Apologies -- the question closed message says "If this question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one."  This is not a question about opening chrome in a new window though so I do not see how it is a duplicate of the linked question. Those answers do not solve my issue.

Comment: [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1638720/edit) your post to clarify why the duplicate does not relate to your problem and let me know, and I'll reopen it. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified, just in case.)

Comment: @harrymc can you clarify why you think this is a duplicate? As I said, the other post is about getting a shortcut to open a new window, not how to launch a shortcut in a separate process. "A process is an instance of a particular executable (.exe program file) running. A given application may have several processes running simultaneously." --https://superuser.com/questions/209654/whats-the-difference-between-an-application-process-and-services

Comment: First, Chrome launches much more than one process. Second, all its windows are managed by one process, even if it seems like there are two such. Having two installations of Chrome is a possible but a doubtful solution, but you don't need our help for trying it out.

Comment: @harrymc so basically... you don't know how to do it so you're not going to let me ask. that's pretty contrary to the spirit of stack exchange.

Comment: As I said, add this information to your post that you're looking to force a separate process. That will make it non-duplicate and I'll reopen it. Please delete all your comments and I'll do the same.