# What's the difference between: a program, process, job, service, daemon, script, command?

Tags: command-line, process, daemon, job-control

Can someone clearly explain what's the difference between these terms?

---

Helpful previous answers:

- [What's the difference between an Application, a Process, and a Service?](https://superuser.com/questions/209654/whats-the-difference-between-an-application-a-process-and-a-service?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

A program is a kind of master that can run different processes.
Processes are typically invoked by a program.
The user does not start a process but a program.

A job is just a scheduled program.

Scripts are not equivalent to commands because scripts are built in a script language that contain much more vocabulary than just executing a command.
Scripts are typically source code in a script language that is not compiled but interpreted on the fly. One possible thing to do with a script language is to invoke commands.

> and are commands equivalent to jobs, or are they rather equivalent to processes ?

This is already explained above.